# MySQL or Tomcat log query

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, logging

I am having trouble with a particular query, it runs perfectly well in SQLYog but not in my JSP page. I get no results in my JSP page and I also get no errors either, but again if I run the same query direct on the database I get the expected results.

I would like to be able to see what query is trying to be sent to the MySQL server, then hopefully I can figure what maybe going astray. Can this be done?

I am using MySQL Server 5.5 for Windows 64bit, Tomcat 7 for Windows 64bit and my connection class is as follows:

```
public static Connection getConnection()
{
    settings settings1 = new settings();
    Connection connection = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + "/" + settings1.db + "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8", settings1.dbUsername, settings1.dbPassword);
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}
```

Any help to enable logging would be much appreciated :-)

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT product.ID, product.partCodePS, product.partCodeManufacturer, product.pName, product.priceCost, product.priceSell, product.reorderLevel, product.location, brand.leadTime, SUM(order_product.unitPrice)
FROM product
INNER JOIN order_product ON (product.ID = order_product.productID)
INNER JOIN brand ON (product.brandID = brand.ID)
INNER JOIN order ON (order_product.orderID = order.ID)
WHERE (product.isWebsite =1 AND order.o_statusID IN (1,2,3,4,5,11,12,14,15))
GROUP BY order_product.unitPrice
```

Comment: Could you add the code which you actually execute sql statement instead of connection part.

Comment: Please, could you post your jsp page in order to see what happens??

Answer (score 0):

You can use [General Query Logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html) MySQL option to view all the queries to MySQL server.

Comment: I have the Error, General and Slow log files enabled, but no sign of any queries appears in the logs, I am using MySQL Workbench > Admin > Server Logs to view them. But no query statements listed.

Comment: @iggyweb, you can find out the log file in explorer and look through it, without any other tools. If there's no your query it means that your query doesn't execute and the error happens before it. Then you can use your IDE (IDEA, for example) for debugging, put breakpoint onto the line "connection = DriverManager.getConnection" and watch, what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your query in jsp page is executed?
can you put the code of your jsp page?

Comment: If I open the JSP page, the query is fired and my page says Sorry your search produced no results, please search again.

If I simply the query in the JSP Page to use only one INNER JOIN the page displays results. If I put the original query back, I get the same Sorry your search produced no results, please search again, no errors are output by Tomcat and the page compiles and displays correctly.

I really need to see what query is attempted to be executed.

Comment: Still haven't got logging enabled, however I have figured out the issue in why the sql is not executing correctly. Its because of the table or should I say reserver word order. To address the table order correctly I should have used order wrapped with single quotes.